# Am I leaking memory here?

Tags: objective-c, iphone, memory-management, iphone-sdk-3.2

Consider the following method, where I build a string and return it. I would like to release the building blocks of the string, but then the string is based on values that no longer exists. Now what?

Am I leaking memory and if so, how can I correct it?

```
- (NSString) getMiddahInEnglish:(int)day{
NSArray *middah = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Chesed", @"Gevurah", @"Tiferes", @"Netzach", @"Hod", @"Yesod", @"Malchus"];
NSString *firstPartOfMiddah = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@", [middah objectAtIndex: ((int)day% 7)-1]];
NSString *secondPartOfMiddah = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@", [middah objectAtIndex: ((int)day / 7)]];

NSString *middahStr = [NSString string@"%@ She'bi@%", firstPartOfMiddah, secondPartOfMiddah];

[middah release];
[firstPartOfMiddah release];
[secondPartOfMiddah release];

return middahStr;
```

}

At the end of the method, the return string, `middahStr` has not been released. Is this a problem? Am I leaking memory?

Comment: Unrelated to memory management, but the argument list for `initWithObjects:` needs to be terminated with `nil`. Otherwise you're just waiting for a crash.

Comment: @Chuck, right. I forgot about that. I'm obviously new at this game... EDIT: What about a missing `nil` causes a crash?

Comment: Without the nil, NSArray doesn't know where the argument list ends and will keep walking the stack until it hits a 0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quite the opposite: You are over-releasing.

`middah` you alloc and init. Then you release it. All is well.

`firstPartOfMiddah` and `secondPartOfMiddah`, you call an NSString "stringWith" convenience method. This is equivalent to invoking alloc, init, **and autorelease.** Your releasing them is a mistake, as they are essentially given to autorelease to release later.

`middahStr` you call the convenience method, but return it. All is well. It will be released later by the autorelease pool.

Rule of thumb (I'm sure there are plenty of exceptions): If you don't alloc it, don't release it.

Comment: so I can just remove the second and third `release` and then I'm all good?

Comment: Moshe: Yes, that should do it.

Comment: Why don't you use Instruments to detect memory leaks? caveat emptor: sometimes they give false positives :)

Comment: @zakovr]yrya - I was confused by my code, my concern was not the leak, but the proper way to build the string without leaking. By the way, what does `emptor` mean?

Comment: Read this to understand memory management in Objective-C:
http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.html
I know, it's long, but you're gonna need it to have a clear picture.
In regards to emptor: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caveat_emptor

Comment: @zakovyrya - According to the wiki, `emptor`= `buyer`? Cool. I learned me some Latin tonight. Awesome! Thanks.

Comment: Instruments is just a tool. There's nothing like learning the idioms. :)